# Laravel model with preloaded relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship, laravel-relations

I have a DB table that stores my job titles so as not to duplicate them, and the Job model has relationships internally, so when I use the Eloquent Model I have to always call or load the JobTitles model over and over again. Is there a way to always use the Job Model with pre-loaded JobTitles inside?

```
    class Job extends Model
    {
        use Notifiable;

        protected $fillable = [ ... ];

        protected $hidden = [
        'token',
        ];


    
        public function title()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\JobTitle','job_title_id');
        }

        public function people()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Person','job_person','job_id','person_id');
        }
        
    }
```

This is JobTitle model

```
class JobTitle extends Model
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $table = "job_titles";

    protected $primaryKey = 'job_title_id';

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
    'token',
    ];


    public function jobs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Job','job_title_id');
    }

    
}
```

Now my code inside of the controller looks like this:

```
 $job = Job::all()->load('title');
```

It is working fine but when I am calling jobs from people

```
 $personJobs = Person::find(1)->jobs()->load('title')->get();
```

gives error, Any ideas how this is done?

Comment: isn't it 'title' instead of 'titile'?

Comment: @codeninja yes, I just corrected it but this was not a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To always use the Job Model with pre-loaded JobTitles inside. you can add `$with` attribute in your job model:

```
class Job extends Model
{
   use Notifiable;
   
   protected $with = ['title'];

}
```

Comment: Yes I have also used $with, found it in official documentation. But forgot to answer to my question thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When calling a relation by the method `$person->jobs()` you will end up with a query builder, so  you can't call the model methods like `load()` since you dont have an instance of a model.

It would be more efficient to call for the relations before getting the first result ([nested eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#nested-eager-loading))

```
$person = Person::with('jobs.title')->find(1);
$personJobs = $person->jobs;
```

If you dont want to query the person data from the database you should use whereHas

```php
$personJobs = Job::whereHas('people', function($personQueryBuilder) {
    $personQueryBuilder->where('id',1);
})->with('title')->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

`load()` is executed after the query has been executed. It's called lazy-loading. Eager loading is using `with()`.

Eager loading is generally faster than lazy loading (I could be wrong on this one, correct me if I'm wrong).

Also, using `jobs()` or any other relationship, this will return the relationship object itself, while accessing it via `->Jobs` will execute the relationship query and will return a collection (if many) or model (if one).

The reason why  `$personJobs = Person::find(1)->jobs()->load('title')->get();` doesn't work is because you're essentially saying "The jobs hasMany relationship will load the "title" which won't work because `hasMany` doesn't have the `load()` function.

So if you want to solve this, you can do `Person::with('jobs.title')->find(1)` or `Person::find(1)->load('jobs.title')`

Comment: `Person::with('jobs.title')->find(1)` did gives me also the persons data

Comment: @HydyrAvezberdiyew in that case, use `$personsJobs = Person::find(1)->Jobs->load('title')`;

Comment: But you advise to use  with(), is not it?  @jeremy

Comment: @HydyrAvezberdiyew the problem can be solved by either load or with, it's just a matter of knowing which and where to use it.

Comment: @HydyrAvezberdiyew personally, I try to use with() as much as possible. I typically use load() on conditionals. If something will be used in any case for the entire function, then I use with()